# What can I do to link between comment of my photos in facebook and in my site?

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer, data-synchronization

Right now I'm planning to rebuild again my site. But I would like to make it synchronized what I posted in facebook/my site. What I want is when I posted a photo to my site, I would like it to be synchronized to my facebook directly without Facebook Share feature, can I do it?. Since the photos can be commented, if someone commented my photo in my facebook, I would like the comment of that photo in my site is updated also. Can I do that? and How can I do that? Can I make it vice versa also? When the photo in my site are commented, I would like in my facebook also updated.

Comment: So your website is essentially a front end to your wall on facebook? Is there any content that would be on your website that wouldn't be on facebook?

Comment: yes..ummm..I just want what I posted about my products in my site, is also posted in my facebook, including the comments that given by the visitors/customers. And of course in my site, there still a lot of contents that not related to facebook. Only my products are related to facebook. Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share updated photo of your website on Facebook then you have to just post image on Facebook and make status as new image or Logo of my website. As per my view, you should not upload only one photo but you have to share link of website which will automatically include photo from your website and also helps to increase traffic. This is easy way to share your updated website.